# Sets which are open "modulo a nullset"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

A set $A$ is said to have [property of Baire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_property) there exists an open set $U$ such that $A\triangle U$ is meager.

So this says that symmetric difference of $A$ and some open set is small (in the sense of category). Another notion of "smallness", which is often used, is measure. So we could ask about sets such that there exist an open set $U$ with $A\triangle U$ is a [nullset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set).<sup>1</sup>

> - Is the class of sets defined as $\{A\subseteq X; \text{there exists an open set $U$ such that }m(A\triangle U)=0\}$ studied? What is known about this class of sets?
> - Does the above class contains all closed sets? All Borel sets? All Lebesgue measurable sets?

It is possible to ask the above questions only in contexts where the notions of *open set* and *nullset* make sense. So let us consider $X=\mathbb R$ or $X=\mathbb R^n$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. (But if something can be said in greater generality, I will be interested to know about it, too.)

<sup>1</sup> This is not the only possibility how to get "measure analogy" of Baire property. If we replace "open set" in the above definition of Baire property by "$F_\sigma$-set" or "$G_\delta$-set", we get another possibility how to get an analogous notion for measurability. This way is perhaps more natural, since in this way the measure-analogue gives us precisely the measurable sets. See, for example, remarks on p.21 in Oxtoby's book Measure and Category.

Comment: Any [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set) seems to be an example of a closed set which does not have the above property. I have posted details [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15473858#15473858).

Comment: Two (of possibly many) places where a general framework for this idea appears are John Morgan's 1989 book [**Point Set Theory**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0824781783) and Ho/Naimpally's paper *An abstract model for measure and category*, **Mathematica Japonica** 24 #1 (1979), 123-140. The 1979 paper is based on S. M. Francis Ho's 72 1975 Master's Thesis **An Abstract Model for Measure and Category** (under Naimpally, Lakehead University, 72 pages). I have not seen the Master's Thesis, but I have to other two items. (I'm glad I bought Morgan's book back in 1990 or so, given it's price now!)

Comment: Another possibly useful reference, one that I have known about since the early 1990s but had forgotten about until yesterday, is the following paper: Ionel Ţevy, *Idéaux d'ensembles et la propriété de Baire* [Ideals of sets and the Baire property], **Revue Roumaine de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées** 15 (1970), 1069-1077. MR 44 #390; Zbl 204.22601 Incidentally, the on-line [MR-Lookp webpage](http://www.ams.org/mrlookup) says the paper is in Russian, but this is incorrect (and disagrees with the published paper version of Math. Reviews).

Comment: As a follow-up to an earlier comment, I now have a copy of S. M. Francis Ho's 1975 *Master of Science* thesis [**An Abstract Model for Measure and Category**](https://knowledgecommons.lakeheadu.ca/bitstream/handle/2453/859/HoS1975m-1b.pdf), and the correct paging for it is "v + 36 pages". The "72 pages" information I gave earlier was either incorrectly listed where I found it, or refers to the paging details for a separately printed Lakehead University preprint series version.